# IOS/Objective-C: Removing NSLog statements for Release and Build Settings in 2018

Tags: ios, release, nslog

A lot of tutorials and answers on SO from the 2008 to 2013 eras say you should remove NSLog statements before releasing an app on the Apple store due to the high overhead of NSLog.

However, by default, Apple seems to have two build configurations, Debug and Release and when you archive the app for release, it now seems to automatically assign the Release configuration.

My question is, in light of this, do you still need to remove the NSLogs or does the Release configuration now automatically do this for you?

Many of the previous answers suggest making an entry in the pch file which no longer exists by default. If you use an alternative debugger apparently you are supposed to make an entry in the Preprocessor Macros however this is beyond my level of knoweldge.

Can anyone shed some light on the preferred approach to the NSLog issue today.